# Woocommerce is setting the Term ID rather than the Term name on Product Attribute

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

What i am trying to do is if the user selects a Taxonomy attribute then is should fetch the terms id and set it into the options but, while doing so it just sets the id in the attribute variation rather than the name of the term

```
public static function create_product_attribute($product,$attribute_data){
        
        $id = [];
        function matchTerms($attribute,$types,$isTaxonomy){
            $term_id = [];
            ($isTaxonomy == true) ? $options = (array) $attribute : $options = (array) $attribute->get_options();
            
            foreach($options as $option){
                
                ($isTaxonomy == true) ? $name = $option->name : $name = get_term($option)->name;
                foreach($types as $type){
                    
                    if(strtolower($type) == strtolower($name)){
                        array_push($term_id,($isTaxonomy == true) ? $option->term_id : $option);
                    }
                
                }
                
            }
            return $term_id;
        }
        
        foreach($attribute_data as $input_attribute){
            $attributes = (array) $product->get_attributes();
            $attribute = new KKART_Product_Attribute();
            
            $attribute->set_name($input_attribute['name']);
            if(strpos($input_attribute['name'],'pa_') !== false){
                $terms = get_terms([
                    'taxonomy' => $input_attribute['name'],
                    'hide_empty' => false,
                ]);
                $term_id = matchTerms($terms,$input_attribute['types'],$isTaxonomy = true);
                
                // $terms = [];
                // foreach($term_id as $term){
                    // array_push($terms,get_term($term)->name);
                // }
            }
            
            (!empty($term_id)) ? $options = $term_id : $options = $input_attribute['types'];
            
            $attribute->set_options($options);
            $attribute->set_position( 1 );
            $attribute->set_visible( 1 );
            $attribute->set_variation( 1 );
            $attributes[$attribute->get_name()] = $attribute;
            $product->set_attributes($attributes);
            
            array_push($id,$product->save());   
            
        }
        return $id;
    }
```

The data in `$attribute_data is:

```
[

    {"name":"Color","types":["red"]},
    {"name":"pa_material","types":["Type"]}

]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that when the term_id gets passed in the backend it works fine, but when you check it on the attribute product section it just shows the term id not name for that you just need to save the attribute and let it reload, But even if you dont save it and keep it untouched, it will work fine for the end user.